# Work with multiple branches locally but pushing once

Tags: git, branch, local

is there a way to work locally on different branches, commiting, merging, checkout, etc. But without pushing? I would like to work in different branches in my project, but push everything at once and to correct branches.

For example:

1. merge branch1 into branch2
2. checkout branch3
3. few commits in branch3
4. checkout branch2
5. few commits in branch2
6. now push everything into correct branches

done

Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing forcing you to push before you want to do it (assuming you have another solution for remote backup).

Comment: No : it asks you to commit, not to push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing forcing you to push before you want to do it (assuming you have another solution for remote backup).

So yes, you can work in your various branches and push only when you're ready to publish your work to other users.

Comment: but git forces me to push local commits before checkout another branch

Comment: No : it asks you to commit, not to push. And you can even avoid commiting, by using `git stash`.